# Write queryDSL to find unique error messages from sys log data?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, querydsl

Is there a way to configure the elasticsearch analyzer so that it is possible to get unique error messages in different scenarios?

1."...July 2020 23:00:00.674z... same message....."
2. slight changes in the string :
message1: "....message_details.. (unknown error 20004)
message2: "....message_details.. (unknown error 278945)
OR
message1:"....a::::: message_details ...."
message2:"....a:f23ed:fff:ff:: message_details ...."
The above two messages are the same apart from the character differnce.

Here is the query :

```
    GET log_stash_2020.06.16/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "Error"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "type": "lab_id"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "log_message": {
      "significant_text": {
        "field": "message",
        "filter_duplicate_text": "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 1000
}

I have added the sample log file.

{
        "_index" : "logstash_2020.06.16",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "################",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "logsource" : "router_id",
          "timestamp" : "Jun 15 20:00:00",
          "program" : "some_program",
          "host" : "#############",
          "priority" : "27",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-06-16T00:00:01.020Z",
          "type" : "lab_id",
          "pid" : "####",
          "message" : ": ############### send failed with error: ENOENT -- Item not found (No error: 0)",
          "@version" : "1"
        }
      }

{
        "_index" : "logstash_2020.06.16",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "################",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "################",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-06-16T00:00:02.274Z",
          "type" : "####",
          "tags" : [
            "_grokparsefailure"
          ],
          "message" : "################:Jun 15 20:00:18.908 EDT: mediasvr[2546]: %MEDIASVR-MEDIASVR-4-PARTITION_USAGE_ALERT : High disk usage alert : host ##### exceeded 100%  \n",
          "@version" : "1"
        }
      }
```

Is there a way to do it in python ?(If elasticsearch does not have above mentioned functionality)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Elasticsearch Python client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io) like so:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 

es = Elasticsearch(...)
resp = es.search(index="log_stash_2020.06.16", body={<dsl query>})
print(resp)
```

where  is whatever query you want to run like the one you gave in the question.

<disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the Elasticsearch client and employed by Elastic>

Comment: A small clarification.I want to write query DSL. I think your answer clarifies only the first part. Can you please help me with the query DSL?

Comment: Specifically I want to write elastic search query to get unique error messages from sys log data. Please let me know from where I can use get some help.No luck at elastic search forum